# Как убрать префикс в soap сообщение?

Tags: java, soap

```
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <acc:test xmlns:acc="http://test/">
                <acc:TestRq test="1">
                    <*acc*:ID>123</*acc*:ID>
                    <*acc*:DEPID>123</*acc*:DEPID>
                </acc:TestRq>
            </acc:test>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

     <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <acc:test xmlns:acc="http://test/">
                <acc:TestRq test="1">
                    <ID>123</ID>
                    <DEPID>123</DEPID>
                </acc:TestRq>
            </acc:test>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
@XmlType(propOrder = { "id", "depid" }) 
@XmlRootElement(name = "TestRq") 
public class TestRq extends TestRequest {
@XmlElement(name = "ID", required = true) 
protected String id; 
@XmlElement(name = "DEPID", required = true) 
protected String depid;
```

Comment: Вы про пространства имен `SOAP-ENV:`?

Comment: То что сейчас -- <acc:ID>123</acc:ID>
ТО что требуется <ID>123</ID>

Comment: `<test xmlns="http://test/">` и так далее. А так, как вы создаете xml?

Comment: Покажите как выглядит тот ваш класс, как вы его сериализуете в xml

Comment: В вопрос, пожалуйста. Комментарии для большого кода не предназначены. Кнопка `править`